# Minimal full SBT project with plugins

Tags: scala, sbt

So sbt (0.10) produces the weirdest errors when I try to create a project that has any kind of configuration, not even copying the wiki examples works…

Is there a nice collection of minimal, working sbt projects? (not the basic/quick `.sbt` stuff but the full `.scala` files in `project/`) The wiki snippets seem to be outdated or wrong somehow…

My attempt at integrating [scalariform](https://github.com/olim7t/sbt-scalariform) failed with SBT not being able to compile `import sbt._` in `project/plugins/Plugins.scala`?! (without any other custom files in the tree. That should have worked as far as I understand it…)

Basically I need a project with `scalariform` and the `-deprecated` compiler option (that didn't even work in quick mode…)

Comment: What version are you using? If it is 0.10.x (latest) make sure to use this doc: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki

The google site is for the older versions..

Comment: For xsbt (0.10.x), I have made https://github.com/VonC/xsbt-template , but it might not be as complete as you need.

Comment: 0.10, edited my question. I must have found only 0.7 examples…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use sbt **0.10.x** (xsbt), you'll have to wait a bit. Currently the plugin is not compatible:

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/sbt-0.10-plugins-list

If you use sbt **0.7.x**, the instructions on the `sbt-scalariform` github page should work.

Comment: ah, I just ignored the "switching" guide thinking it only concerned more advanced features… so the weirdly whitespace-aware `.sbt` file is now the main configuration point?

Comment: @pascal: as illustrated by https://github.com/VonC/xsbt-template/blob/master/build.sbt, yes. But only for the "light configuration" (https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Basic-Configuration). The full Configuration (https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration) is a Scala class (no more whitespace issue there)